# amateur webhosting/xampp stuff

Tags: url, hosting, ip, xampp

Alright I know this is more than likely a amateur question but I have to ask anyways. I have my web hosting set up like this. I bought my domain name through a service and then set that up so it would go to no-ip.com and through that service I have the port 80 redirect to another port. So now when I go to my domain it shows my ip with my redirected port on the end. (xx.xxx.xx.xx:####) My question is this...is there any way ,besides cloaking because I don't like how that puts everything in a iframe, to set this up that instead of showing my ip address it shows the regular domain name. If not it's okay I just wanted to know! Thanks in advance, sorry I'm a noob!

Comment: Have the domain name resolve to the final ip address and then have people go to domain:port.  Other than that, there's not a non-sucky solution (other than getting a proper server or a proper connection).

Comment: @Corbin I figured I didn't have much hope ha, o well thanks! I guess I might as well pay for a hosting company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a domain goes to a specific address. The domain system does not handle ports, so there's no way to have it resolve to a specific port. So, to deviate from 80, it has to be explicit unless another server is interfering (iframe, proxying, whatever). Anyway, an ISP that allows web servers, a shared hosting package, or a low end VPS should all fit your needs.

Comment: De nada.  Tu pregunta me recuerda de cuando estaba empezando a hacer websites :).

Comment: Oh also, as a side note: if your site is just a fun little experimental site that will be low traffic (and thus availability doesn't matter and performance isn't critical), I would consider getting a low end VPS.  That way you get to mess with everything server related (if you're the type that likes that).  Decent LE VPS can be found for ~$8-10/mo, but they're not particularly stable.  (I should also note though that running a server yourself would of course mean bigger security risks and more complexity).  Just noting it since it's very close to the price of decent shared hosting.

Comment: Haha yep I am just starting out I guess that is pretty apparent!

Comment: Eh, I just guessed it because most PHP coders (well really web-targeted languages) in general tend to start with stuff hosted on their own computers and then run into the exact problem you had :).